# Alternative to WPF combo box dropdownstyle

Tags: wpf, combobox

In system.windows.forms, a combo box had a DropDownStyle.  Unfortunately, I hate the style of a readonly combo box in WPF, and there is no longer the ability to set the DropDownStyle/FlatStyle to is there an easy way to simply never use the ugly gray "button"-looking combo box and always use the appearance as though it is a text box with a drop down arrow?

I hope I'm making sense...  Accomplishing this seems way more difficult than it should be.

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Toggle `IsEditable` and that will give you the style right away.

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True">
    <!-- items -->
</ComboBox>
```

If you don't want the text box to be editable, also set `IsReadOnly`:

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True">
    <!-- items -->
</ComboBox>
```

The text in the text box still highlights when you select something, but it can't be edited as it's read-only.

Comment: That's what I thought; strangely enough, setting IsEditable to  true didn't seem to help on a particular read only combo box...  Any other factors which would cause this anomaly?

Comment: Does it have its own control template? What does its XAML look like?